# Hibernate HQL Mapping unusual column-name

Tags: hibernate, hql, hibernate-mapping

Good evening!

I have been learning and partially using hibernate for some time now and ran into troubles using hql joins.

I followed these instructions just for practice and see how it even works...
http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0350__Hibernate/HSQLJoinTwoClasses.htm

He basically creates 3 classes:
Supplier, Product, Software
One Supplier has many Products
Many Products have One Supplier

Everything worked just fine... except that I cant understand one particular thing that prevents me from implementing that into my own code. 
This is the part that I just cant understand:

```
<class name="Product">

   <id name="id" type="int">
      <generator class="increment"/>
   </id>

   <property name="name" type="string"/>
   <property name="description" type="string"/>
   <property name="price" type="double"/>

   <many-to-one name="supplier" class="Supplier" column="supplierId"/>
</class>


<class name="Supplier" >
  <id name="id" type="int">
     <generator class="increment"/>
  </id>

  <property name="name" type="string"/>
  <bag name="products" inverse="true" cascade="all,delete-orphan">
    <key column="supplierId"/>
    <one-to-many class="Product"/>
  </bag>

</class>

The query would be:
SELECT s.name, p.name, p.price 
     FROM Product p INNER JOIN p.supplier AS s";
```

Why is he using "supplierId" as column value when there is no supplierID defined everywhere. I can't figure out what is going on in the background or why it is even working...

I have been searching for an explanation for ages.. hope one of you has made some experiences like that and can help me. Would be really great. Hope I wasn't too vague.

Have a nice day,
Michael Kargl

---

## Solution

The problem was that I missed that the actual Foreignkey column in the database is called supplierID...

```
create table Product(
       id int, 
       name varchar,
       description varchar,
       price decimal(6,2),
       >>>> supplierid int <<<<<
)
```

(I will never copy and paste code like that ever again..)
 The rest is greatly explained by [@carbontax's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11072448/1177024) and [@MikkoMaunu's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11070703/1177024)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say that `supplierId` is not defined, but it is.

When you write `<many-to-one name="supplier" class="Supplier" column="supplierId"/>` in the Product definition you are defining `supplierId` as a field on the Product class.

In the Supplier class you are telling Hibernate that for the `products` collection the name of the foreign key in the Product class is `supplierId`.

Hibernate will translate this information into an "ON p.supplierId=s.id" sql clause when you execute your HQL statement.

Comment: Awww how could I have missed THAT..
You have now idea of how embarrassed I am right now.
Never the less.. thanks for the great explanation!
It made quite some things clearer! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In

```
 <many-to-one name="supplier" class="Supplier" column="supplierId"/>
```

value of column defines name of the foreign key column in Product table. Foreign key contains some primary key value of Supplier table.
This column materializes relation between Product and Supplier in database. Without such a column there is no relationship between Product and Supplier in database.
Bag is then inverse side of this relationship.

Similar case can be found from [Hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#assoc-bidirectional-m21).

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation! Embarrassing that I missed that "detail".. But thanks for the great explanation! Short and clear.. I got somehow really confused ;) Thanks you two! Have a nice day!